# how to use Node Domain module

Tags: node.js

I'm new in node and still learning node and javascript, wrote some code and make a site with help of tutorials like [that](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1210041/). but when ever an exception thrown my server shut itself down, for solution i tried to implement domain module. but couldn't find any tutorials. With some research and code and fix, implement domain now my server doesn't shut down itself but i couldn't use my routes because don't know how to use it with domain.run function. Any suggestion for what to search or any tutorials i can look it up or explain how to use it with exampel? I mean for dummies. thanks in advance.

Comment: How about http://nodemon.io/

Comment: thanks but i really wanted to learn how to use domain.js, and how to write proper code with it. what is the better way to use it, should i create domain for every request or create domain and start server in it. I move my code in domain.run callback function and it's working but i don't know this is the right way to do it.